# Python project printing output incorrectly and index off by one

Tags: python, python-3.x

Everything works in this program as intended except for two things. If you enter a boy name it will print everything correctly except it will add the print line "(name) was not ranked in the top 100 girl names...." and the same result when entering a girls name. Any thoughts on how to make it stop? Also the 'pos' that is returned is off by one-- is there a counter I can add to fix this?

```
 try:
        boyfile = open("boynames2014.txt", "r")
        girlfile = open("girlnames2014.txt", "r")
        boynames = [line.strip() for line in boyfile]   #read the content to a list
        girlnames = [line.strip() for line in girlfile] #read the content to a list

except IOError:
    print("Error: file not found")


#Input gender
#search names in lists

gender = input("Enter gender (boy/girl): ")
if gender == "boy" or gender == "girl":
    name = (input("Enter name to search for: "))
else:
    print("Invalid gender")


if name in boynames:
    pos = boynames.index(name)
    print(name, "was ranked #", pos, "in 2014 for boy names")
else:
    print(name, "was not ranked in the top 100 boy names for 2014")


if name in girlnames:
    pos = girlnames.index(name)
    print(name, "was ranked #", pos, "in 2014 for girl names")
else:
    print(name, "was not ranked in the top 100 girl names for 2014")



boyfile.close()
girlfile.close()
```

Comment: Isn't printing `(boy) was not ranked in the top 100 girl names` the programmed behavior? It's off by one because Python is 0 indexed.

Comment: I suppose it is, but I do not want it to be.  If a boy name is used it should not print the line from the top 100 girls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking both boy and girl names regardless of gender, you can add another condition to check `gender`.

```
if gender == "boy" and name in boynames:
    pos = boynames.index(name) + 1
    print("{} was ranked #{} in 2014 for boy names".format(name, pos))
elif gender == "girl" and name in girlnames:
    pos = girlnames.index(name) + 1
    print("{} was ranked #{} in 2014 for girl names".format(name, pos))
else:
    print("{} was not ranked in the top 100 {} names for 2014".format(name, gender))
```

As for `pos` being 1 off, this is because lists are 0 indexed. Meaning the first item starts at index 0, second at index 1 and so on. so if your ranking starts at #1 then you just need to offset it by 1.

```
pos = boynames.index(name) + 1
```

Finally I would suggest you close your files inside the `try/except` after reading as well since you don't use them anywhere else in the code there is no need to leave them open.

Comment: Yes. Additionally, you might want to better handle Invalid gender otherwise this will give some errors and unintended results if you leave it to just print.

Comment: Alright, I really appreciate it! I'm brand new to Python and programming so this is all still learning period for me.

Comment: You're welcome, by better handle I mean ensure that `name` is defined since you conditionally define it. So either move your main code inside the if statement where you define `name` or match the conditions. Either chage `else` to `elif gender in ('boy', 'girl')` or as c.z. has demonstrated.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what else I could do to the Invalid gender besides using print? That's the only way I have learned it so far.....  Any suggestions? A website to read how to do it differently? Thanks so much!

Comment: Ahhh ok, now that makes more sense than what is in the textbook!  I have honestly learned more from people on here than my class....

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `name` against both `boynames` and `girlnames` no matter what the gender was.

I'd suggest adding a conditional:

```
if gender == "boy":
    if name in boynames:
        pos = boynames.index(name)
        print(name, "was ranked #", pos, "in 2014 for boy names")
    else:
        print(name, "was not ranked in the top 100 boy names for 2014")

elif gender == "girl"    
    if name in girlnames:
        pos = girlnames.index(name)
        print(name, "was ranked #", pos, "in 2014 for girl names")
    else:
        print(name, "was not ranked in the top 100 girl names for 2014")
```